# Python tabstop-aware len() and padding functions

Tags: python, function, padding, string-length, tabstop

Python's `len()` and padding functions like `string.ljust()` are not tabstop-aware, i.e. they treat '\t' like any other single-width character, and don't round `len()` up to the nearest multiple of tabstop. Example:

```
len('Bear\tnecessities\t')
```

is 17 instead of 24 ( i.e. 4+(8-4)+11+(8-3) )

and say I also want a function `pad_with_tabs(s)` such that

```
pad_with_tabs('Bear', 15) = 'Bear\t\t'
```

Looking for simple implementations of these - compactness and readability first, efficiency second.
This is a basic but irritating question.
@gnibbler - can you show a purely Pythonic solution, even if it's say 20x less efficient?

Sure you could convert back and forth using `str.expandtabs(TABWIDTH)`, but that's clunky.
Importing math to get `TABWIDTH * int( math.ceil(len(s)*1.0/TABWIDTH) )` also seems like massive overkill.

I couldn't manage anything more elegant than the following:

```
TABWIDTH = 8

def pad_with_tabs(s,maxlen):
  s_len = len(s)
  while s_len < maxlen:
    s += '\t'
    s_len += TABWIDTH - (s_len % TABWIDTH)
  return s
```

and since Python strings are immutable and unless we want to monkey-patch our function into string module to add it as a method, we must also assign to the result of the function:

```
s = pad_with_tabs(s, ...)
```

In particular I couldn't get clean approaches using list-comprehension or `string.join(...)`:

```
''.join([s, '\t' * ntabs])
```

without special-casing the cases where `len(s)` is < an integer multiple of TABWIDTH), or `len(s)>=maxlen` already.

Can anyone show better `len()` and `pad_with_tabs()` functions?

Comment: It's not clear what it is you want or how str.expandtabs doesn't fit the bill. Some example input and output would help clarify.

Comment: I said what I want in the first line: 
implementations of both len() and string.ljust() which are tabstop-aware.

str.expandtabs() doesn't fit the bill because it blasts the tabs to spaces. We don't want that if we only want to measure len(). It seems wasteful to generate a throwaway copy by taking len(string.expandtabs(s))

Comment: "It seems wasteful to generate a throwaway copy by taking len(string.expandtabs(s))"  Why?  It seems simple and clean to me.  Do you have any specific profile numbers that indicate that this is the bottleneck in your application?

Comment: If you *really* need the performance, just write the functions in C

Comment: Folks - let's just neglect efficiency and go for compact readable Pythonic code? (even if it's say 20x less efficient)

gnibbler has a good solution, any other entries?

Comment: @smci: You provided compact readable code in your question.  Then said you didn't like it.  First: you already provided the most compact and readable code in your question.  Second; you asked about performance.  If you want to ask a different question, please ask a new question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
TABWIDTH=8
def my_len(s):
    return len(s.expandtabs(TABWIDTH))

def pad_with_tabs(s,maxlen):
    return s+"\t"*((maxlen-len(s)-1)/TABWIDTH+1)
```

Why did I use `expandtabs()`?
Well it's fast

```
$ python -m timeit '"Bear\tnecessities\t".expandtabs()'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.602 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit 'for c in "Bear\tnecessities\t":pass'
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.32 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit '[c for c in "Bear\tnecessities\t"]'
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.17 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit 'map(None,"Bear\tnecessities\t")'
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.25 usec per loop
```

Anything that iterates over your string is going to be slower, because just the iteration is ~4 times slower than `expandtabs` even when you do nothing in the loop.

```
$ python -m timeit '"Bear\tnecessities\t".split("\t")'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.868 usec per loop
```

Even just splitting on tabs takes longer. You'd still need to iterate over the split and pad each item to the tabstop

Comment: `pad_with_tabs` should probably call `my_len` instead of `len`, in case there are embedded tabs in the string to be tab-padded.

Answer (score 1):

I believe gnibbler's is the best for most prectical cases. But anyway, here is a naive (without accounting CR, LF etc) solution to compute the length of string without creating expanded copy:

```
def tab_aware_len(s, tabstop=8):
    pos = -1
    extra_length = 0
    while True:
        pos = s.find('\t', pos+1)
        if pos<0:
            return len(s) + extra_length
        extra_length += tabstop - (pos+extra_length) % tabstop - 1
```

Probably it could be useful for some huge strings or even memory mapped files. And here is padding function a bit optimized:

```
def pad_with_tabs(s, max_len, tabstop=8):
    length = tab_aware_len(s, tabstop)
    if length<max_len:
        s += '\t' * ((max_len-1)//tabstop + 1 - length//tabstop)
    return s
```

Answer (score 0):

`TABWIDTH * int( math.ceil(len(s)*1.0/TABWIDTH) )` is indeed a massive over-kill; you can get the same result much more simply. For positive `i` and `n`, use:

```
def round_up_positive_int(i, n):
    return ((i + n - 1) // n) * n
```

This procedure works in just about any language I've ever used, after appropriate translation.

Then you can do `next_pos = round_up_positive_int(len(s), TABWIDTH)`

For a slight increase in the elegance of your code, instead of

```
while(s_len < maxlen):
```

use this:

```
while s_len < maxlen:
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I was unable to make use of accepted answer "as is" so here goes slightly modified version just in case someone would run into same problem and discovers this post via search:

```
from decimal import Decimal, ROUND_HALF_UP
TABWIDTH = 4

def pad_with_tabs(src, max_len):
    return src + "\t" * int(
        Decimal((max_len - len(src.expandtabs(TABWIDTH))) / TABWIDTH + 1).quantize(0, ROUND_HALF_UP))


def pad_fields(input):
    result = []
    longest = max(len(x) for x in input)
    for row in input:
        result.append(pad_with_tabs(row, longest))
    return result
```

Output list contains properly padded rows having tab count rounded so the resulting data will have same indentation level regardless of corner .5 cases when no tab gets added in the original answer.